# mysqldump via launch daemon on mac osx not working

Tags: macos, mac, bash, launchd, launchctl

I'm trying to create a mysqldump of a database via bash script, and automate the process by using Mac's launchd / launchctl process. I can successfully run the bash script manually to backup the db in terminal, but if I try to use launchd, nothing seems to happen.

Anyone know what might be the issue?

Here is the bash script for the mysqldump:

```
DT=`date +%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S`
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump --opt -u root -proot --host=localhost extrapolation > /Users/[user]/Desktop/db/extrapolation_$DT.sql
```

and here is the plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>extrapolation_db_backup</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/[user]/Sites/extrapolationlaunch/dbase_backup.sh</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>120</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

which I've saved in /Users/[user]/Library/LaunchAgents

I then run:

launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/extrapolation_db_backup.plist`

and if I use

`launchctl list`

I can see the process:

```
-   0   extrapolation_db_backup
```

My guess is maybe some sort of permissions issue but I haven't been able to work it out. Any help would be appreciated.